# How to declare @ symbol in password in postgres shell script

Tags: postgresql, shell

I am getting error while running postgres script in shell script.
Password for PostgreSQL contain @ special character.

```
#!/bin/sh
# This is a comment!

psql "postgresql://$USERNAME:"Admin@123"@$HOST/$DATABASE" -f /config/postgresqlpurge.sql
```

I expect script should be executed, but getting error 
" to address: Name or service not known "123'@XXXX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PostgreSQL connection string is a [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) and must follow the encoding rules.

Use %40 instead of @.

Comment: ~psql "postgresql://$USERNAME:"Admin%40123"@$HOST/$DATABASE" -f /config/postgresqlpurge.sql~ Now I m getting authentication failed  This is my password : Admin@123 How can I write

Comment: You should not have double quotes inside the URI.